# Blank Figure in Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I use the below function, I get the plot shown in the window but the figure saved is blank.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

def plot_embeddings(embeddings, names):
model = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0)
vectors = model.fit_transform(embeddings)
x, y = vectors[:, 0], vectors[:, 1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
for i, tname in enumerate(names):
    ax.annotate(tname, (x[i], y[i]))
plt.show()
plt.savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

I haven't found a solution that works.

Comment: use `savefig()` before `show()`

Comment: @furas do you know why `show()` clears the image?

Comment: @furas plz put it as answer, I will accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `savefig()` before `show()`

`show()` open window and wait till you close it and maybe when it closes window then it clears image.